# Rasa - ‘from_entity’ mapping for a non-existent entity

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-sdk

This Rasa issue seems to not really be described by the “Warning” (and the “Warning” in this case is effectively an error). It has this message for every slot and entity:

`/rasa/shared/utils/io.py:99: UserWarning: Slot ‘name’ uses a ‘from_entity’ mapping for a non-existent entity ‘name’`. Skipping slot extraction because of invalid mapping.

Of course, it’s not literally true:

*From domain.yml:*

```
slots:
  name:
    type: text
    initial_value: null
    mappings:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: name
```

*From nlu.yml:*

```
- intent: provide_name
  examples: |
    - My name is [John Doe](name)
    - You can call me [Sara](name)
    - [James](name) is my name
    - they call me [Biggie Smallz](name)
    - [Yun Fan](name)
```

I have also tried several variations and tried appending an entity list to nlu.yml:

```
entities:
- name
```

My original slots syntax was more concise (this is one of a few variations).

```
slots:
  name:
    type: text
    mappings:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: name
```

I’ve tried running with `debug = True`, `log_level: DEBUG`, `-vv`, Python versions 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10, as well as deleting caches. The model builds without error using `rasa train`. In fact, if I build the `nlu` component only with `rasa train nlu` I can run it and see that entity extraction works fine.

Additionally, when I put a debugger in the source code I see the `domain_slots.items()` look like this:

> ('name', {'type': 'text', 'initial_value': None, 'mappings': [{'type':
> 'from_entity', 'entity': 'name'}]}),

Comment: Was the entity for `name` definition included in your domain file?

Comment: @LeoGuagenti It was. Although, I've kind of moved on since I was working on this 6 months ago, so I no longer have it easily accessible for troubleshooting.